# Weird UserId Returned By Student Submission

Tags: java, google-classroom, userid

I've been trying to get the email of the user that submitted a response to a short answer assignment. In all of my other experiences using the Google Classroom API, the "userId" parameter has been the student's email address, but when I call getUserId on the StudentSubmission object, I get a weird string of numbers. How do I get the email associated with the submitted response?

Here's my code for reference:

```
ListStudentSubmissionsResponse submissionResponse = service.courses().courseWork().studentSubmissions().list(courseId, assignmentId).execute();
List<StudentSubmission> submissions = submissionResponse.getStudentSubmissions();
for (StudentSubmission sub : submissions)
{
    System.out.println(sub.getId() + "\t" + sub.getUserId() + "\t" + sub.getState());
}
```

And this is the response that I am getting:
`Cg4I2vWq_8IDEIWck4DDAw  108878473486432178050   CREATED`

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: Don't not read [the docs](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-coursework#retrieve_student_responses): "Students are identified by the **unique ID** or email address of the user, as returned by the Google Admin SDK." So there's clearly no guarantee it will be the email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't not read the docs: [*retrieve_student_responses*](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-coursework#retrieve_student_responses)

> Students are identified by the **unique ID** *or* email address of the user, as returned by the Google Admin SDK.

So there's clearly no guarantee it will return the email..

If you read the docs you can find how to properly retrieve the email for a student id: [*retrieve_a_users_profile*](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-users#retrieve_a_users_profile)

> To retrieve the abridged profile, including ID and name, for a user, call `userProfiles.get()` with the user's ID, email, or "me" for the requesting user.
>
> To retrieve the `emailAddress` field, you must include the **`classroom.profile.emails`** scope.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I must've looked over that when I was reading the doc.

Answer (score 1):

There is published documentation on this API... no need to ask here: https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest

More specifically, there are userProfile APIs that differentiate an "id" from an "emailAddress".

https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/userProfiles

Now that said, there are no guarantees according to the JSON schema, being just a "String" type ... as to what the value might be.

"emailAddress" should be just that but "id" could be whatever the local system uses to identify principals - which is almost definitely NOT going to be the email address. It will instead be some global identifier for whatever principal management system is being used.

Comment: I was well aware of the api. I was just confused on why there wasn't any reference to the separate userProfiles API when from my experience the userId and email were interchangeable.

Comment: Fair point - was more of a comment regarding the other answers to not read the docs. Glad it worked out and there appears to be separate fields for email and userId; respectively. Hopefully this answers the question or another post did.